# Object is null. How to set it? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a variable FirstThreads of type `List<Thread>`.

I am trying to do the following, but FirstThreads is always null.

```
FirstThreads.AddRange(Threads.Skip<Thread>(PageIndex * PageSize)
            .Take<Thread>(PageSize));
```

I can't do this:

```
FirstThreads = FirstThreads.AddRange(Threads.Skip<Thread>(PageIndex * PageSize)
                                            .Take<Thread>(PageSize));
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before you can interact with the `FirstThreads` variable, you need to make the 
variable refer to a `List<Thread>` instance, like this:

```
firstThreads = new List<Thread>();
```

You can also write

```
firstThreads = Threads.Skip<Thread>(PageIndex * PageSize).Take<Thread>(PageSize)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize your `List<FirstThreads>` first.

The default value of any object is `null`.

For example:

```
List<FirstThreads> firstThreads = new List<FirstThreads>();
firstThreads.AddRange(collection);
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to instantiate the list first, I assume it is a `List<Thread>`?

so

```
FirstThreads = new List<Thread>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate the List object:

```
List<Thread> FirstThreads = new List<Thread>();
```

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt the 'new' keyword is always worth a shot

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
FirstThread = 
    new List<Thread>(Threads.Skip<Thread>(PageIndex * PageSize)
                            .Take<Thread>(PageSize));
```

Or if you're not sure whether it has items and is already instantiated

```
(FirstThread ?? FirstThread = new List<Thread>())
    .AddRange(Threads.Skip<Thread>(PageIndex * PageSize)
    .Take<Thread>(PageSize));
```

Note:

You can probably take out the `<Thread>` for the `Skip` and `Take` methods, as it will be inferred.

Answer (score 1):

THe thing is, if you write FirstThreads.AddRange you're implying FirstThreads is an object with the AddRange method; but FirstThreads is null, that means that it's empty (so it has no methods).
You would have to make FirstThreads an empty list:

```
FirstThreads = new List<Thread>();
```

Answer (score 1):

FirstThreads either was set to null or is never initialized.  Either way my guess is you need to create an object to assign to it.

FirstThreads = new <-- visual studio will auto complete object creation code